# web UI test automation using etaoin and Clojure, how to fill/find relative elements?

Tags: selenium, clojure, automation, automated-tests

In html page contains input tag and label tag, I locate label tag using its text and by using that I want to locate and fill out input tag.

e.g

```
<div class="el-form-item is-error is-required">
  <label for="address.streetAddress.text" class="el-form-item__label">
    Specify your shipping address
  </label>
  <div class="el-form-item__content">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" required="required" placeholder="" class="el-input__inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

From etaoin docs,

```
(query driver {:fn/has-text "Specify your shipping address"})
```

Above code gives me label element using which I want to fill out input value.

I don't know how other frameworks like selenium solves this problem.

Also I can't use any css attributes to look out for input tag.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you can locate element by XPath then use `//label[.="Specify your shipping address"]/following-sibling::div/input`

Comment: The easiest way would be to add either a unique ID or CSS class to the desired input element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know how to do this in `etaoin`, but use can use [the Forest library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/docs/forest.adoc#workign-with-sibling-nodes) to manipulate plain hiccup/html if that will help.

```
(with-debug-hid
    (with-forest (new-forest)
      (let [root-hid        (add-tree-hiccup
                              [:div {:class :some-div-1}
                               [:div {:class :some-div-2}
                                [:label "Some Junk"]
                                [:div {:class :some-div-3}
                                 [:label "Specify your shipping address"]
                                 [:div {:class :some-div-4}
                                  [:input {:type        "text" :autocomplete "off" :required "required"
                                           :placeholder "" :class "el-input__inner"}]]]]])
```

We want to find the :input node in the same :div as the :label node with text "Specify your shipping address". We then find its parent, and use the parent as the beginning of a new search for the desired :input node:

```
label-path                   (only (find-paths root-hid [:** {:tag :label :value "Specify your shipping address"}]))
parent-div-hid               (-> label-path reverse second)
shipping-address-input-hid   (find-hid parent-div-hid [:div :div :input])
```

Unit test show it working:

```
(is= label-path [:0006 :0005 :0004 :0001])
(is= parent-div-hid :0004)
(is= (hid->hiccup shipping-address-input-hid)
  [:input {:type        "text", :autocomplete "off", :required "required",
           :placeholder "", :class "el-input__inner"}])
(value-set shipping-address-input-hid "1234 Main St")
(is= (hid->hiccup shipping-address-input-hid)
  [:input {:type         "text", :autocomplete "off", :required     "required",
           :placeholder  "", :class        "el-input__inner"}
   "1234 Main St"])
```

We can output the final modified tree:

```
(hid->hiccup root-hid) =>
    [:div
     {:class :some-div-1}
     [:div
      {:class :some-div-2}
      [:label "Some Junk"]
      [:div
       {:class :some-div-3}
       [:label "Specify your shipping address"]
       [:div
        {:class :some-div-4}
        [:input
         {:type "text",
          :autocomplete "off",
          :required "required",
          :placeholder "",
          :class "el-input__inner"}
         "1234 Main St"]]]]]
```

You can also [see a lightning talk](https://youtu.be/RtavTnRr0oM) from Clojure Conj 2017.